# XPath using contains in this situation?

Tags: text, xpath, contains, html

The situation in HTML:

```
<div class="someDivision">
   <span class="firstSpan">...</span>
   <span class="firstSpan">...</span>
   <span class="firstSpan">
      <span class="secondSpan">...</span>
      <span class="secondSpan">
         "Unique text"
         <a>"Text which I need"</a>
```

I need access to the text contained in `<a>`.

Comment: In the topic thread I wrote XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div[@class='someDivision']
  /span[class='firstSpan']
    /span[class='secondSpan' and contains(text()[1], 'Unique text')]
      /a[1]
         /text()[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if it's "How do I get the text in an `a` element that's preceded by a text node containing `"Unique text"` and is inside a `span` element with a `class` attribute equal to `secondSpan`, which itself is inside a `span` element with a `class` attribute equal to `firstSpan`, which itself is inside a `div` element with a `class` attribute equal to `someDivision`?" then this XPath should do the trick:

```
div[@class='someDivision']/span[@class='firstSpan']/span[@class='secondSpan']/a[contains(preceding-sibling::text(), '&quot;Unique text&quot;')]/text()
```